# When accessing a UI element from another class using dispatcher, the UI element is null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class which needs to update my UI. Currently I am calling a function held in the UI class and passing through the what needs to be updated.
eg

```
public class someclass
{
    public someclass()
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.DrawGrid(Brushes.Black);
    }
}

public class MainWindow
{
...
    public void DrawGrid(Brush colour)
    {
        ReturnGrid().background = colour;
    }
}
```

But this has issues with threading, so I updated my code to use the dispatcher.

```
public class someclass
{
    public someclass()
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.DrawGrid(string "black");
    }
}

public class MainWindow
{
...
    public void DrawGrid(Brush colour)
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {ReturnGrid().Background = colour};);
    }
    public Grid ReturnGrid()
    {
        return maingrid; //defined in xaml
    }
}
```

However this throws up an error that the returned grid is null.
However if I called DrawGrid from MainWindow it would work fine.

EDIT: Data binding approach

```
public class someclass
{
    public someclass()
    {
        MainWindow.testbackground = Brushes.Black;
    }
}

public class MainWindow
{
public static Brush testbackground = Brushes.White;
...
}
<MainWindow x:Name="mainwindow" ...>
...
<Grid ... Background="{Binding testbackground ElementName=mainwindow}"/>
</MainWindow>
```

Comment: `main.DrawGrid(string "black");` thats not going to compile. The routine takes a `Brush`...

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, it's not possible to tell you what you did wrong. That said, the main thing you've done wrong here is to write code to modify the UI explicitly from code-behind. You should be using MVVM and data binding as WPF is intended to be used, so that the framework can handle updating the UI on your behalf automatically.

Comment: Sorry was trying to code it from memory. Fixed code.

Comment: Are you really creating a new `MainWindow`, setting one property, and then discarding it unused? Or did you just edit your code down drastically for the question?

Comment: An MVVM approach using a data binding does not work. I have added an edit into my original post to show what I have tried.

Comment: Code is edited down drastically.
My actual project is around 10000 lines of code long and I didn't want to add all of it.

In actual terms its a program which opens a peer to peer connection to the same program on another machine (via IP), and then my class is for the client, when it receives data it then parses it and then tries to set the UI accordingly. Eg, if a colour is passed through the net, it decodes the colour and then sets the element's background to be that colour.

Comment: @Fumbleless An MVVM approach using databinding works perfectly, if it is done correctly. You should use that approach and find out where you went wrong in your first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

The root issue here is caused by the fact XAML-defined controls are created via deferred way (i.e. asynchronous). Once instantiating a WPF window, you have to wait for `Loaded` event triggered. Before that, all your visuals are null values and `DrawGrid()` method would fail.

```
public class someclass
{
    public someclass()
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.Loaded += Window_Loaded;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        main.DrawGrid(Brushes.Black);
    }   
}
```

Surely, this is just a sample. This is your responsibility to un-tie the event handler once you do not need it anymore, check the event occurrence triggered is caused exactly by the flow you expect, etc.

Comment: My code is drastically edited down. In actual fact the code calling for the UI change is called after the window has fully loaded.

Comment: @Fumbleless, could you remove the irrelevant code then, because it's too many of versions there

Answer (score -2):

Despite not following WPF's MVVM standard good programming practices, I have found a simple solution.

```
public class someclass
{
    public somelcass()
    {
        MainWindow.gridbackground = Brushes.Black;
    }
}

public class MainWindow
{
    public static Brush gridbackground = Brushes.White;
    public DispatchTimer timer;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        timer.Tick += checkbackground;
        timer.Start();
    }
    private void checkbackground(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        grid.Background = gridbackground;
    }
}
```

Creating a static variable and a dispatch timer to periodically check for changes works.

Comment: But surely you have more things to update, not just the background color? This approach seems hard to scale. Your binding code seems a little bit strange: the binding has now way of telling when the static filed changes. Are you still interested in an answer with proper bindings?